# How do I get Ubuntu 18 to "see" my Dell 1135n MFP's scanner?

Tags: dell, scanner, sane

Ok, so this MFP is ***ancient***, but it is a workhorse and mine still runs like a champ. The 1135n printer driver works, but I can't get Simple Scan to find the scanner. My device is on my home network at 192.168.1.60. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, this is a very simple fix.

```
sudo nano /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf
```

At the end of the file, add these two lines:

```
#Dell MFP Laser Printer 1135n
tcp 192.168.1.60 9400
```

If your printer is configured with another IP, use that. Bring up Simple Scan and it should see it now.